# Calculating percentage in sql not working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
select country_of birth, count(*)/(select count(*) from person)*100 
from person
group by country_of_birth;
```

However, it's not getting the correct result.

Comment: Sample data and what you think the correct result is would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing the down sides of *integer division*.

In PostgreSQL, the result of the division of two integers is again an integer (the truncated result).

So `7 / 3 = 2` in PostgresSQL.

If you want an exact result, cast to `numeric`:

```
CAST (7 AS numeric) / CAST (3 AS numeric)
```

You can omit one of the casts, because PostgreSQL will automatically cast to the more generic numeric data type if the types of the arguments are different.

Comment: Depends where. You should ask a separate question (or read the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this will fix the problem of incorrect results, but I would encourage you to use window functions:

```
select country_of_birth,
       count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as percentage
from person
group by country_of_birth;
```